# How to make checkboxes of Bootstrap table responsive

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have used `reactjs-bootstrap-table` to create Bootstrap Table. The issue I am facing is with the checkboxes in table that we use to select the rows.

In some systems checkboxes are getting displayed properly while in others edges of checkboxes are getting cut from right side:

[image]

I think it is due to screen resolution. But instead it should be responsive. Below is my code:

```
          <div className="col-md-12 summary-tile-text_sum_3 attribute-table" id="tableDesign" key="2" style={{ paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
              <div className={this.state.scroll}>
                <BootstrapTable data={Sampledata}
                  headers={this.props.state.options.headers}
                  select={this.props.state.options.select}
                  tableClass={this.props.state.options.tableClass}
                  activeClass={this.props.state.options.activeClass}
                  selected={this.props.state.selected}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  onSort={this.onSort}
                  keyName="index"
                  columns={sampleColumns}
                  >
                  <div style={{ padding: '8em' }} className="well well-success">
                    <p>No Data to Load.</p>
                  </div>
                </BootstrapTable>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Props value:

```
options: {
    tableClass: "table table-bordered table-hover",
    activeClass: "info",
    resize: true,
    headers: true,
    select: 'multiple',
    disableSelectText: false
  }
```

`sampleData` and `sampleColumn` contains the data being dispalyed in the screenshot above.

After debugging the issue I found out that it is happening because of the following CSS:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

but, I cannot remove this, as it will cause the table to go outside the window.

Is there any other alternative to table-layout? I want to display the checkboxes same as it is displaying in the blue header of the image.

Comment: Can you provide the dummy values for the Sampledata, Samplecolumns, props

Comment: I have updated in description. Please check.

Comment: Can you provide the dummy values for the Sampledata

Comment: These are same as displayed in the image. Those values we are fetching from the response of API by mapping through the JSON data.

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

I'm using:

```
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
"reactjs-bootstrap-table": "^1.0.12"
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BootstrapTable from 'reactjs-bootstrap-table';

require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');

const options = {
    tableClass: "table table-bordered table-hover",
    activeClass: "info",
    resize: true,
    headers: true,
    select: 'multiple',
    disableSelectText: false
}

let data = [
    { id: 1, 'Index': '1', Attribute: 'Dummy', Group: 'Dummy' },
    { id: 2, 'Index': '2', Attribute: 'Dummy', Group: 'Dummy' },
    { id: 3, 'Index': '3', Attribute: 'Dummy', Group: 'Dummy' },
]
let columns = [
    { name: 'Index' },
    { name: 'Attribute' },
    { name: 'Group' }
]

export class Tmp extends Component {
    onSort(col, dir) {
        this.props.sort(col, dir);
    }

    onChangeSelectText(e) {
        this.props.setDisableSelectText(e.target.checked);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-md-12 summary-tile-text_sum_3 attribute-table" id="tableDesign" key="2" style={{ paddingLeft: "30px" }}>
                    <BootstrapTable
                        columns={columns}
                        data={data}
                        headers={options.headers}
                        select={options.select}
                        tableClass={options.tableClass}
                        activeClass={options.activeClass}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        onSort={this.onSort}
                        selected={true} >
                        <div style={{ padding: '8em' }} className="well well-success">
                            <p>No Data to Load.</p>
                        </div>
                    </BootstrapTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Tmp
```